# How to install a package in Solaris 11 from file?

Tags: package-management, solaris, mysql, pkg

How to install a package in Solaris 11 from file (not from the package repository)?

I am trying to install a `.pkg` file on a Solaris 11 SPARC machine, however, I get errors:

```bash
# pkg install mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.30-solaris11-sparc-64bit.pkg

pkg install: The following pattern(s) did not match any allowable packages.  Try
using a different matching pattern, or refreshing publisher information:
 mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.30-solaris11-sparc-64bit.pkg
```

The file `mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.30-solaris11-sparc-64bit.pkg` is already copied to the SPARC machine.

How may I install a package file from disk?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/pkg-1.html) to install local file you should use command like:

```
pkg install -g file://mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.30-solaris11-sparc-64bit.pkg
```

`-g` is to add temporary repo as installation source.